# Read Private google Spreadsheet in React (with Auth)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth, spreadsheet

I want read JSON value from Google Spreadsheet with "no public link" in react, i don't know it will work how and to get "login status As owner of the sheet" then showing, i used tableTop before but it only work with public link..

heres my code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { GoogleLogin } from 'react-google-login';
import key from './config';

const responseGoogle = (response) => {
    console.log(response);
}

class SheetAPI extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      data: []
    }
  }

  async fetchingData (){
    const API_KEY = key.apiKey;
    const SHEET_ID = key.Spreadsheet;
    const response = await fetch('https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/'+ SHEET_ID +'/values/Sheet1!A4:F21?key='+API_KEY); // batchGet for any range
    const json = await response.json();
    // just log ‘json’
    var sheets = json.values;
    console.log('sheet-json:' + sheets);
  }
  


 componentDidMount() {
    
  }



  render() {
   
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <GoogleLogin
        clientId="id"
        scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly"
        onSuccess={responseGoogle}
        isSignedIn={true}
        hostedDomain = "myorganization.com"
        icon = {false}
        >
        
        </GoogleLogin>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SheetAPI;
```